# Exchange text label to select value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a box entitled by label "Data sprzedaży":

```
<div class="formField">
        <label for="invoice_invoice_sale_date">Data sprzedaży</label>
                <?php draw_date_selects('invoice_sale_date', date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'))?>

                <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to put there dropdown with 3 options.
If I choose one of 3 options, it will replace the default label.

Comment: Do you have any code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first thing you need to do is pass the option value to a variable, from there you can replace the text of the label with the option value:

```js
$(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
 labelText = $(this).val(); // Get value of selected option
        $('label').text(labelText); // Pass selection option value into label
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formField">
    <label for="invoice_invoice_sale_date">Data sprzedaży</label>
    <?php draw_date_selects('invoice_sale_date', date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'))?>

    <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>

<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select an option</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Near. And how to do that instead of the title "Data sprzedaży" appear immediately dropdown?